# Interstitial ads from iAd aren't working on swift

Tags: xcode, swift, iad, interstitial

I'm trying to implement interstitial ads however my code doesn't seem to work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

var interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
var interAdView: UIView = UIView()
var closeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.setTitle("x", forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "close:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
loadAd()
}
func close(sender: UIButton) {
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}
func loadAd() {
    println("load ad")
    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd.delegate = self
}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("ad did load")

    interAdView = UIView()
    interAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.addSubview(interAdView)

    interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

    interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("failed to receive")
    println(error.localizedDescription)

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}
}
```

ads aren't showing up, for some reason the app is even tracing "ad did load" but the ad doesn't show up. Sometimes I get the error where xCode tells me that more than 10 instances of ads are being shown at once, yet I haven't been presented with even one ad. What could be the issue? Also it'd be a plus if somebody can tell me how I can make the ad show up after the level ends, but if you can't its all good. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781298/iad-interstitials-not-showing-consistently-and-not-at-all-on-the-simulator/31906335#31906335). I've never been able to implement them reliably since their introduction on iPhone. Personally, I'd suggest using AdMob interstitials if you don't mind dealing with another ad network. Way more reliable with a higher fill rate.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new SKScene and added this into the file:

```
class Advertisement11: SKScene, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {
    var interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    var interAdView = UIView()
    var closeButton = UIButton()
    var returnToScene = SKScene()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 30, 30)
        closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        closeButton.setTitle("x", forState: .Normal)
        closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "close:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        loadAd()
    }

    func close(sender: UIButton) {
        closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
        interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
        let block = SKAction.runBlock {
            self.view?.presentScene(self.returnToScene)
        }
        self.runAction(block)//this is to go back to the previous Scene
    }

    func loadAd() {
        print("load ad")
        interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
        interAd.delegate = self
    }

    func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("ad did load")

        interAdView = UIView()
        interAdView.frame = self.view!.frame
        view!.addSubview(interAdView)

        interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

        interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
    }

    func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

    }

    func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("failed to receive")
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    //  interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```