# adding interstitial iAd ads in iOS SpriteKit game swift

Tags: ios, swift, iad, interstitial

I've been trying to accomplish this for what feels like a lifetime. If somebody can post what they've used for their own game and how they implemented it, that would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to have an interstitial ad show up after my `ShowGameOver()` function. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31906335/2108547). I've never been able to implement them reliably since their introduction on iPhone. Personally, I'd suggest using AdMob interstitials if you don't mind dealing with another ad network. Way more reliable with a higher fill rate.

Comment: here is the answer I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839488/interstitial-ads-from-iad-arent-working-on-swift?noredirect=1#comment51730490_31839488