# iAd interstitial ads not working on sprite kit app Xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I'm trying to implement interstitial ads with iAd into my spriteKit game. My code is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

var interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
var interAdView: UIView!


var closeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)
closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
closeButton.setTitle("x", forState: .Normal)
closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "close:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}

func close(sender: UIButton) {
closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func loadAd() {
println("load ad")
interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
interAd.delegate = self
}
func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
println("ad did load")

interAdView = UIView()
interAdView.frame = self.view!.frame
view!.addSubview(interAdView)

interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
println("failed to receive")
println(error.localizedDescription)

closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
interAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

This code delivers me more problems than it does results. Unfortunately I am a beginner at implementing any sort of ads into an app and I don't know how I can change any of this in my favour.

One issue I get is that output traces `ad did load` (as you can see thats supposed to be traced once the ad is presented) however when `ad did load` is traced no ad is presented. I wait for at least 3 minutes but nothing happens.

Another issue I have is this `WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.`, but this is printed after the function to load the ad is called once or twice.

Comment: try to change viewDidAppear to viewDidLoad.

Comment: nope, still the same issue but thank you for trying :)

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781298/iad-interstitials-not-showing-consistently-and-not-at-all-on-the-simulator/31906335#31906335). I've never been able to implement them reliably since their introduction on iPhone. Personally, I'd suggest using AdMob interstitials if you don't mind dealing with another ad network. Way more reliable with a higher fill rate.