# Can't see banner for iAds

Tags: xcode, swift, iad

[image: This is the screen right before the game]Does any body else have the problem were they can't see the banner for iAds but when you first run the app a big blue screen shows up and says your now connected to iAds. I'm running my app an my iPhone and my iAD developer app testing fill rate is set to 100%

Code:

```
   import UIKit
    import StoreKit
    import SpriteKit
     import GameKit
      import iAd


     extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:   .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

  }

  class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate      {
var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadInterstitialAd()
    ADBannerView()


    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }




    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
            vc.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))

        }
    }








    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }



}



override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}


  func loadInterstitialAd() {
interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()
interstitialAd.delegate = self
  }

  func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

  }

  func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
interstitialAdView = UIView()
interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
view.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
 }

func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
 }

  func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
return true
  }

  func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

  }

  func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
   }

   }
```

Comment: That big blue screen is your interstitial ad. Do you want to have interstitial ads? Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31906335/2108547) for some guidance on how to implement them if you do.